# CollectionType field showing empty after manually submitting Symfony Form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.7

I have OneToMany relationship

Book <----* BookImage

**Book:**

```
oneToMany:
      bookImages:
            targetEntity: BookImage
            mappedBy: book
            cascade: [persist,remove]
```

**BookImage:**

```
manyToOne:
       book:
            targetEntity: Book
            inversedBy: bookImages
            joinColumn:
              name: book_id
              referencedColumnName: id
```

So my Form has a collectionType field.

**BookType:**

```
$builder->add('bookImages', 'collection', array(
                'type'         => new BookImageType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
//                'allow_delete'    => true,
                'by_reference' =>false

            ));
```

**BookImageType:**

```
$builder->add('imageName','text',array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(),

            )
        ));
        $builder->add('imageUrl','text',array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(),

            )
        ));
```

Controller to save the data via Ajax Call:

```
public function addNewSellBookAction(Request $request)
{

    $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
    $userId = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $content = $request->get('book');
    $bookData = json_decode($content, true);

    $book = new Book();


    $bookImage1 = new BookImage();
    $bookImage1->setImageName("Amazon Book Image");
    $bookImage1->setImageUrl("http://url1.com");

    $book->addBookImage($bookImage1);

    $bookImage2 = new BookImage();
    $bookImage2->setImageName("Amazon Book Image");
    $bookImage2->setImageUrl("http://url1.com");

    $book->addBookImage($bookImage2);



    $bookData['bookSeller']=$userId;



    $bookForm = $this->createForm(new BookType(), $book);


    var_dump($bookForm->getData()->getBookImages()); //Image Data Before Submit 
    $bookForm->submit($bookData);
    var_dump($bookForm->getData()->getBookImages()); //Image Data After Submit

    if($bookForm->isValid()){
        $em->persist($book);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->createJsonResponse('success',array('successTitle'=>"Book Successfully added to sell List"));
    }else{
        $error= $serializer->serialize($bookForm,'json');
        return new Response($error,200);
    }



}
```

Now BookImage Data Before & After Submit are:

```
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[580]
  private 'elements' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\BookImage)[581]
          protected 'id' => null
          private 'imageName' => string 'Amazon Book Image' (length=17)
          private 'imageUrl' => string 'http://url1.com' (length=15)
          private 'titleImage' => null
          private 'book' => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\Book)[578]
              ...
      1 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\BookImage)[582]
          protected 'id' => null
          private 'imageName' => string 'Amazon Book Image' (length=17)
          private 'imageUrl' => string 'http://url1.com' (length=15)
          private 'titleImage' => null
          private 'book' => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\Book)[578]
              ...
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[580]
  private 'elements' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\BookImage)[581]
          protected 'id' => null
          private 'imageName' => null
          private 'imageUrl' => null
          private 'titleImage' => boolean false
          private 'book' => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\Book)[578]
              ...
      1 => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\BookImage)[582]
          protected 'id' => null
          private 'imageName' => null
          private 'imageUrl' => null
          private 'titleImage' => boolean false
          private 'book' => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\Book)[578]
```

Why after submitting data the collectionType field value got null or empty? Though the other fields have the value perfectly. Can anyone explain? or do I have any problem with the structure? Thanks in advance.

**Book Entity**

```
class Book
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->messages = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bookImages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookTitle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookDirectorAuthorArtist;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookEdition;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookIsbn10;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookIsbn13;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookPublisher;

    /**
     * @var date
     *
     */
    private $bookPublishDate;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookBinding;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookPage;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookPriceSell;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookLanguage;

    /**
     * @var text
     *
     */
    private $bookDescription;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookCondition;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookIsHighlighted;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookHasNotes;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookComment;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookContactMethod;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookContactHomeNumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookContactCellNumber;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookContactEmail;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $bookIsAvailablePublic;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     */
    private $bookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange;
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     */
    private $bookPaymentMethodCheque;
    /**
     * @var date
     *
     */
    private $bookAvailableDate;




    private $bookImages;

    private $bookBuyer;

    private $bookSeller;

    private $messages;





    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookTitle
     *
     * @param string $bookTitle
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookTitle($bookTitle)
    {
        $this->bookTitle = $bookTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookTitle()
    {
        return $this->bookTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookDirectorAuthorArtist
     *
     * @param string $bookDirectorAuthorArtist
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookDirectorAuthorArtist($bookDirectorAuthorArtist)
    {
        $this->bookDirectorAuthorArtist = $bookDirectorAuthorArtist;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookDirectorAuthorArtist
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookDirectorAuthorArtist()
    {
        return $this->bookDirectorAuthorArtist;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookEdition
     *
     * @param string $bookEdition
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookEdition($bookEdition)
    {
        $this->bookEdition = $bookEdition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookEdition
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookEdition()
    {
        return $this->bookEdition;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookIsbn10
     *
     * @param string $bookIsbn10
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookIsbn10($bookIsbn10)
    {
        $this->bookIsbn10 = $bookIsbn10;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookIsbn10
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookIsbn10()
    {
        return $this->bookIsbn10;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookIsbn13
     *
     * @param string $bookIsbn13
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookIsbn13($bookIsbn13)
    {
        $this->bookIsbn13 = $bookIsbn13;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookIsbn13
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookIsbn13()
    {
        return $this->bookIsbn13;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookPublisher
     *
     * @param string $bookPublisher
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookPublisher($bookPublisher)
    {
        $this->bookPublisher = $bookPublisher;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookPublisher
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookPublisher()
    {
        return $this->bookPublisher;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookPublishDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $bookPublishDate
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookPublishDate($bookPublishDate)
    {
        $this->bookPublishDate = $bookPublishDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookPublishDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getBookPublishDate()
    {
        return $this->bookPublishDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookBinding
     *
     * @param string $bookBinding
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookBinding($bookBinding)
    {
        $this->bookBinding = $bookBinding;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookBinding
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookBinding()
    {
        return $this->bookBinding;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookPage
     *
     * @param string $bookPage
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookPage($bookPage)
    {
        $this->bookPage = $bookPage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookPage
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookPage()
    {
        return $this->bookPage;
    }



    /**
     * Set bookLanguage
     *
     * @param string $bookLanguage
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookLanguage($bookLanguage)
    {
        $this->bookLanguage = $bookLanguage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookLanguage
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookLanguage()
    {
        return $this->bookLanguage;
    }

    /**
     * Add messages
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Message $messages
     * @return Book
     */
    public function addMessage(\AppBundle\Entity\Message $messages)
    {
        $this->messages[] = $messages;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove messages
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Message $messages
     */
    public function removeMessage(\AppBundle\Entity\Message $messages)
    {
        $this->messages->removeElement($messages);
    }

    /**
     * Get messages
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookBuyer
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $bookBuyer
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookBuyer(\AppBundle\Entity\User $bookBuyer = null)
    {
        $this->bookBuyer = $bookBuyer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookBuyer
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getBookBuyer()
    {
        return $this->bookBuyer;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookSeller
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $bookSeller
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookSeller(\AppBundle\Entity\User $bookSeller = null)
    {
        $this->bookSeller = $bookSeller;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookSeller
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getBookSeller()
    {
        return $this->bookSeller;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookPriceSell
     *
     * @param string $bookPriceSell
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookPriceSell($bookPriceSell)
    {
        $this->bookPriceSell = $bookPriceSell;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookPriceSell
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookPriceSell()
    {
        return $this->bookPriceSell;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookDescription
     *
     * @param string $bookDescription
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookDescription($bookDescription)
    {
        $this->bookDescription = $bookDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookDescription()
    {
        return $this->bookDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookCondition
     *
     * @param string $bookCondition
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookCondition($bookCondition)
    {
        $this->bookCondition = $bookCondition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookCondition
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookCondition()
    {
        return $this->bookCondition;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookIsHighlighted
     *
     * @param string $bookIsHighlighted
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookIsHighlighted($bookIsHighlighted)
    {
        $this->bookIsHighlighted = $bookIsHighlighted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookIsHighlighted
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookIsHighlighted()
    {
        return $this->bookIsHighlighted;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookHasNotes
     *
     * @param string $bookHasNotes
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookHasNotes($bookHasNotes)
    {
        $this->bookHasNotes = $bookHasNotes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookHasNotes
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookHasNotes()
    {
        return $this->bookHasNotes;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookComment
     *
     * @param string $bookComment
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookComment($bookComment)
    {
        $this->bookComment = $bookComment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookComment
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookComment()
    {
        return $this->bookComment;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookContactMethod
     *
     * @param string $bookContactMethod
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookContactMethod($bookContactMethod)
    {
        $this->bookContactMethod = $bookContactMethod;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookContactMethod
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookContactMethod()
    {
        return $this->bookContactMethod;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookContactHomeNumber
     *
     * @param string $bookContactHomeNumber
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookContactHomeNumber($bookContactHomeNumber)
    {
        $this->bookContactHomeNumber = $bookContactHomeNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookContactHomeNumber
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookContactHomeNumber()
    {
        return $this->bookContactHomeNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookContactCellNumber
     *
     * @param string $bookContactCellNumber
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookContactCellNumber($bookContactCellNumber)
    {
        $this->bookContactCellNumber = $bookContactCellNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookContactCellNumber
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookContactCellNumber()
    {
        return $this->bookContactCellNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookContactEmail
     *
     * @param string $bookContactEmail
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookContactEmail($bookContactEmail)
    {
        $this->bookContactEmail = $bookContactEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookContactEmail
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookContactEmail()
    {
        return $this->bookContactEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookIsAvailablePublic
     *
     * @param string $bookIsAvailablePublic
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookIsAvailablePublic($bookIsAvailablePublic)
    {
        $this->bookIsAvailablePublic = $bookIsAvailablePublic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookIsAvailablePublic
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookIsAvailablePublic()
    {
        return $this->bookIsAvailablePublic;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange
     *
     * @param string $bookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange($bookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange)
    {
        $this->bookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange = $bookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange()
    {
        return $this->bookPaymentMethodCaShOnExchange;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookPaymentMethodCheck
     *
     * @param string $bookPaymentMethodCheck
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookPaymentMethodCheck($bookPaymentMethodCheck)
    {
        $this->bookPaymentMethodCheck = $bookPaymentMethodCheck;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookPaymentMethodCheck
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBookPaymentMethodCheck()
    {
        return $this->bookPaymentMethodCheck;
    }

    /**
     * Add bookImages
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BookImage $bookImages
     * @return Book
     */
    public function addBookImage(\AppBundle\Entity\BookImage $bookImages)
    {
        $this->bookImages->add($bookImages);
        $bookImages->setBook($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove bookImages
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BookImage $bookImages
     */
    public function removeBookImage(\AppBundle\Entity\BookImage $bookImages)
    {
        $this->bookImages->removeElement($bookImages);
    }

    /**
     * Get bookImages
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getBookImages()
    {
        return $this->bookImages;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookPaymentMethodCheque
     *
     * @param boolean $bookPaymentMethodCheque
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookPaymentMethodCheque($bookPaymentMethodCheque)
    {
        $this->bookPaymentMethodCheque = $bookPaymentMethodCheque;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookPaymentMethodCheque
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getBookPaymentMethodCheque()
    {
        return $this->bookPaymentMethodCheque;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookAvailableDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $bookAvailableDate
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setBookAvailableDate($bookAvailableDate)
    {
        $this->bookAvailableDate = $bookAvailableDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookAvailableDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getBookAvailableDate()
    {
        return $this->bookAvailableDate;

    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval($this->id);
    }


}
```

**BookImage Entity**

```
class BookImage
{


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $imageUrl;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     */
    private $titleImage;


    private $book;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageName
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     * @return BookImage
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName)
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImageName()
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageUrl
     *
     * @param string $imageUrl
     * @return BookImage
     */
    public function setImageUrl($imageUrl)
    {
        $this->imageUrl = $imageUrl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageUrl
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->imageUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Set titleImage
     *
     * @param boolean $titleImage
     * @return BookImage
     */
    public function setTitleImage($titleImage)
    {
        $this->titleImage = $titleImage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titleImage
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getTitleImage()
    {
        return $this->titleImage;
    }

    /**
     * Set book
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Book $book
     * @return BookImage
     */
    public function setBook(\AppBundle\Entity\Book $book = null)
    {
        $this->book = $book;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get book
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Book 
     */
    public function getBook()
    {
        return $this->book;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval($this->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read closely whole cookbook entry http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html and for example make sure that you have "adder", "remover" methods etc...

Comment: @Miro I have been searching and trying with many things for last 2 days. Couldn't find neither any problem nor a solution. That is why I need help from you guys.

Comment: @Miro, One thing I want to show you that before & after submission the **book** entity is there all the time. Just the **imageName** & **imageUrl** fields are not there. If the mapping was wrong then how the **book** entity came along?

Comment: @Sujit Please add your book and BookImage entities code also.

Comment: added the entites @vijay4vijju

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but why aren't you letting the form instance handle the request (eg `$bookForm->handleRequest($request);`)? That takes all of the data from the request and passes it on to the form, which in turn  will create the entities you need. It's possible I'm missing something, haven't looked at the question in detail, but it looks as if you're trying to manually handle the submit, which doesn't make sense IMO

Comment: I don't see `$form->handleRequest()` anywhere? Also I don't see your ajax code. You are trying to hack the form which was designed to do all the work for you automatically. I would first try to make the form work without ajax. Once everything works as expected, then add ajax calls. This would make debugging easier

Comment: Actually I am making web api with symfony and application with angular js. So as the data is not coming from the symfony form, using `handleRequest` was not possible. And sometimes the data is not well formatted in json. So I had to manually submit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to find the answer for almost 7 days now and finally came up with a solution. But don't know if it a bad practice or not.

Just have to put the data as an **array** into submitData. After submitting the value will be added to that particular entity via form.

```
public function addNewSellBookAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
        $userId = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();


        $content = $request->get('book');
        $bookData = json_decode($content, true);

        $bookData['bookImages']=array();

        array_push($bookData['bookImages'],array(
            'imageName'=>"Amazon Book Image",
            'imageUrl'=>"http://url1.com"
        ));
        array_push($bookData['bookImages'],array(
            'imageName'=>"Amazon Book Image",
            'imageUrl'=>"http://url1.com"
        ));

        $bookData['bookSeller']=$userId;


        $book = new Book();
        $bookForm = $this->createForm(new BookType(),$book);


        var_dump($bookForm->getData()->getBookImages());
        $bookForm->submit($bookData);
        var_dump($book->getBookImages());

        if($bookForm->isValid()){
            $em->persist($book);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->createJsonResponse('success',array('successTitle'=>"Book Successfully added to sell List"));
        }else{
            $error= $serializer->serialize($bookForm,'json');
            return new Response($error,200);
        }

    }
```

Hope it will help the others.

### Bounty Still Open If anyone provides answer with best practice

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. As per the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) by symfony

Check Task controller line number 20 and 23

```
 $task->getTags()->add($tag2);
```

The tags collection is accessible naturally via $task->getTags() and can be persisted to the database or used however you need.

I think you are missing something here

> $book->addBookImage($bookImage1);

Try this instead

```
$book->getBookImages()->add($bookImage1);
```

Comment: please look at the    addBookImage() method of Book entity. I am adding the **BookImage** entity in the ArrayList perfectly. The solution you are suggesting and what I did is same. So No LUCk for me.

Comment: and I tried with $book->getBookImages()->add($bookImage1);
same result. May be the problem is not with the mapping or assigning. I think the problem is about the form submission. Are you sure I am using the right way to preSubmit the form data?

Comment: @sujit Just remove this  $bookForm->submit($bookData); and try agian

Comment: How I would check the validation of form if I don't submit it?

Comment: If I don't submit the data then further data which is needed for the form and mapping the entity will fail.

Comment: As you answered first, I am giving bounty to you. @vijay4vijju

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to modify images with the request data add new images after you submit the form.

```
$bookForm->submit($bookData);
// ...
$book->addBookImage($bookImage1);
```

Comment: Changing data after submitting isn't the best practice and you still have to validate the `#bookImage1` data remember?

Comment: You change your entity and not the form data and you can still validate your additional entities manually with the validator service.